Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec is frozen and only continues running when the starting program is closed
I have a problem with a Java application (program1) starting another Java application (program2).
If program2.jar has to process a large amount of data, the program2 freezes and only continues running when the program that started it (program1.jar) is closed.
Code in program1.jar is:
String cmd = "java -jar program2.jar";
String[] env = {""};
File dir = new File(directoryPath);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env, dir);

Does anyone have an idea what could help here?
String cmd = "java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -jar program1.jar" does not solve the problem. Is there perhaps another idea how the problem could be solved using the environment settings?

You'll need to provide source code for a [mre] for program2 also.

In simple terms, the app's (program1) Runtime object's stout and stderr (connecting to program2) buffers will run full. Use threads to empty them, or set them to null, or redirect/inherit them like in @Sören's post.

Unfortunately the code of program2 is not available.

Could you help with a link to Sören's post?

Don't use Runtime.exec - it's much harder to use properly than ... Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).inheritIO().start();

The tip about the ProcessBuilder in combination with the inheritIO helped. Thank you very much.

Good. Use a List<String> to initialize it with the command though - it's more flexible
